# how can I print variable in python from another file

Tags: python

I have tow files the first one is: test.py:

```
age_var = 22

def first_code():
   var1 = 'phone'
   var2= 'name'
   var3= 'last_name'
   there are more code down ...........
```

In the second one I Want to print var1 and age_var only, in the test2.py file:

```
from dir.test import *

print(var1)
print(age_var)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Wouldn't you need to call `first_code`?

Comment: The problem is I have more cod in first_code() and I need only one variable.

Comment: `var1` is a *local variable* inside `first_code()`.  It has absolutely no existence outside of the function, whether or not you call it.  You would either need to return the value, or make the variable global, to access it from anywhere else.

Comment: I have the age_var is the global var, but when I try to print age_var in the test2.py, all my codes has been run in the terminal

Comment: @mansour32 edit the question. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: In `test2.py` do you want to print both `var1` and `age_var` or only `age_var`? Because `var1` is local, what do you mean by printing its value outside the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make all the variables global that you want to use outside of that function you can do that by doing

```py
def first_code():
    global var1
    var1 = 'phone'
    etc...
```

and then import the test.py file into test2.py by doing this if test and test2 are in the same dir

```py
from test import *
```

do this if test and test2 are in different directories, first make sure that the dir that has test.py has a file called `__init__.py` this file can be empty, this is so python know that that dir is a package next import it like this

```py
from directory.name.fileName import *
```

so in your case

```py
from directory.name.test import *
```

remember to change `directory.name` to your directory replacing all the
/s with .s

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Since `var1` is defined inside `first_code`, you'll need to have that function `return var1`, and then *call* the function from the other module so that `var1` will get defined and then returned.

```
# First file

age_var = 22

def first_code():
    var1 = 'phone'
    var2= 'name'
    var3= 'last_name'
    # more code...
    return var1


# Second file

from dir.test import age_var, first_code

print(first_code())  # this is var1, because first_code returns it
print(age_var)       # this was imported from dir.test
```